# postgresql streaming replication - Master Server keeps all the archives and this is filling up my HD

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication, archive

Is there a way to run cleanups on Master Server for these archive files that are older and are not needed for the slave server for streaming replication?

Comment: You are talking about *archives* and not the active WAL files in `pg_wal`, right? Why are they needed for streaming replication? Is it because you use `restore_command` on the standby server?

Comment: yes, I use `restore_command` on the standby server and on the master server I have 
`archive_mode` turned on with `archive_command` in postgresql.conf file

Comment: Why not just use streaming with a replication slot instead of archive_command and restore_command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the recovery parameter [`archive_cleanup_command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-CLEANUP-COMMAND) together with the `pg_archivecleanup` command:

> ```
> archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main %r'
> ```

That command assumes that the WAL archives are accessible in `/mnt/server/archivedir` on the standby server.

Note that for PostgreSQL versions older than v12, this has to be specified in `recovery.conf`.

If you don't have an easy way to access the WAL archives from the standby, you could use an NFS mount.

Comment: I'm using postgresql v10 and followed this link [https://www.scalingpostgres.com/tutorials/postgresql-streaming-replication/]
and it has been a while now using this and now this directory on my master server which has archives is just filling up.

I have `archive_mode = on` 
and 
`archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/%f'`

in Masters postgresql.conf

Comment: Then just do as I said in the answer.

Comment: My recovery.conf file is on my standy server and the archives are happening on the master server which is on a different server and it's archive folder can't be accessed from standby server. Can you suggest what should be done?

Comment: Do something that is similar to your `restore_command`, except it removes all older files.

Comment: like what? in V10

Comment: Since your question doesn't contain the `restore_command`, how should I guess, lacking clairvoyance?

Comment: this set up is just a hot standby replica of masters PostgreSQL database cluster,
So I think if I have `archive_mode` and `archive_command`turned off on main server there shouldn't be any issue in replication

Comment: Use an NFS mount, as in my extended answer.